# Comparing the contents of 2 cells and then copying any differences into a new cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Essentially I am looking to compare the contents of 2 cells and then populate a new cell with the difference.  The 2 cells that I am looking to compare the contents of are both list containing product names.  An example would be:

Cell 1 contains A,b,c,d
cell 2 contains b,c

I would like cell 3 to then populate with A and D

I am essentially looking to do the opposite of a vlookup function but don't know how I would go about doing that.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Can you better define your problem (I'm not sure how you got "A and B" as the desired return value in your example)? Can you also show us what you've attempted so far, and why your attempts have failed?

Comment: Oops that was a typo.  I corrected it.  A and D would be my desired return value since A & D are located in only Cell 1 and not Cell 2.  Im thinking I need to use some sort of reverse match function but still trying to figure that out

Comment: Use `Split(cellValue, ",")` to create arrays from each cell then loop over the elements in the first array and use `Match()` to see if they're contained in the second array.

Comment: To build on what Tim is suggesting (Which will only work if the things you want to compare are separated by commas or another character) you split each cell in a different array, then with a nested For loop, you compare each element of the first array with each element of the second array. If at some point there is a match, set a boolean value to true. After the  inside loop, but still inside the outside loop, have an If condition to check if the match boolean is True. If it is, add that value to the cell 3

Comment: After splitting the substrings, you could use a Dictionary or Collection to count the number of repeated substrings, then join together only those with a count of `1`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a UDF you could use for this:

```
' Returns a `delimiter`-joined list containing
' items from minuend (a `delimiter`-joined list)
' but not items from subtrahend (a `delimiter`-joined list)
Public Function SET_SUB(minuend As String, subtrahend As String, Optional delimiter As Variant)
    If IsMissing(delimiter) Then delimiter = "," ' Set default delimiter as comma

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim emptyList As Boolean: emptyList = True

    ' Retrieve list items
    Dim fullSet As Variant
    Dim removeSet As Variant
    fullSet = Split(minuend, delimiter)
    removeSet = Split(subtrahend, delimiter)

    SET_SUB = ""

    ' Loop through subtrahend, removing matches
    For i = 0 To UBound(fullSet)
        If IsError(Application.Match(fullSet(i), removeSet, 0)) Then
            SET_SUB = SET_SUB & fullSet(i) & delimiter
            emptyList = False
        End If
    Next

    ' Remove last delimiter for non-empty list
    If Not emptyList Then
        SET_SUB = Left(SET_SUB, Len(SET_SUB) - Len(delimiter))
    End If
End Function
```

Drop that in a module and the function will be accessible on your worksheet (information on UDFs [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-Custom-Functions-in-Excel-2007-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f) if you're unfamiliar).

It takes the items in the first list, removes the items in the second list, and returns the set difference. You can optionally add a "delimiter" argument if you want lists separated by something other than commas.

**Building off your example:**

*A1* = a,b,c,d

*A2* = b,c

*A3* = `=SET_SUB(A1, A2)` = a,d

**For a semicolon-delimited list:**

*A1* = a;b;c;d

*A2* = b;c

*A3* = `=SET_SUB(A1, A2, ";")` = a;d